# MVC - LESS not compiling properly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less

[image]

I am trying to compile a LESS file to CSS. The same lines of code is compiling perfectly fine in online tools. Tried it in around 5 tools. But for the same thing it is breaking in my code.

I have a mixin which is using unit.

```
.mixinbgwcollleftmenu(@mixinbgwcollleftmenupt){
display: inline-block;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: bottom;
width: 100%;
padding-top: unit(@mixinbgwcollleftmenupt, vh);}
```

When I use this, I am getting the error. **Expected '}' but found 'i' on line 634 in file** But when I try to remove that line of code, and just write it simply, the whole app is breaking, and I am getting the error in the picture.

Things I have tried.

1. The app was running dotless on visual studio, I uninstalled it. I tried compiling it on client side via the CDN, same error.

   2. I removed the unit line of code, and hard coded it for testing. The special characters show up.
   3. And when the special characters come up, I get a 500 error altogether.
   4. I removed the line of code and the variable in the function altogether, and the same characters appear.

Comment: What file extension is your .mixinbgwcollleftmenu class in? A .cshtml file, or a .less file, or ...?

Comment: @BrianOgden, its in .less

Comment: What was the block that contains line 634?